# lightDM GTK greeter won't log in unless root

Tags: 14.04, root, login-screen

I've been building an Ubuntu distro from the ground up, and I decided to use the LightDM GTK Greeter. Everything is going good, until I decide to log in to the non-root account. If I try to log in to any account that isn't the root one, it simply goes black for a minute, then shows the login screen again. How can I get greeter to log into the non-root account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to fix it!

I needed to remove the X server I was using, and replace it with the default server included in Ubuntu.